# Is the phrase 'Они пойдут на концерт' the correct translation of 'They'll go to the concert?'

Tags: грамматика, вид, глаголы-движения

I've already tried to use Tatoeba/reverso.net to find out whether the phrase is acceptable. They didn't seem to give much information, so I decided to check here.

I really just had two issues:

A) If you didn't know whether they walked or drove, would you use пойти or поехать (поедут)?

B) Would you use a perfective verb?

Thanks for any help given

Comment: A) Correct; B) What imperfective form to you have in mind? "Они будут идти на концерт"?

Answer (score 6):

Yes and yes.
You can use пойдут even if they are driving. Here it has the meaning of attend. Ребенок ходит в школу even if he is actually going by bus (and perhaps even having online lessons).

Perfect aspect is fine. If you use будут ходить it will mean repeatedly or periodically.

Answer (score 2):

*Они пойдут на концерт?* is a pretty correct, idiomatic, and acceptable sentence.

The choice of the verb in the pair *пойти — поехать* depends on context.

If it goes about a concert hall where audience enters it walking on foot and the question is about potential visitors, then the default verb is *пойти*, while *поехать* will be used only if ‘they’ live so far away that it completely excludes walking all the way, for example, they are now in another country, in a distant town, so far away the transport should be inevitably concerned: *поехать* will be used if you ask about a rock band and a concert *in another town* where different bands will play and this band is also invited but still hesitating whether to take part of not. Or about devoted fans, but also ‘they’ and ‘the concert’ are quite a way apart. In short: *поехать* is not needed unless the concert is in a far-away place.

As for the aspect, it depends upon the situation. If by that question you want to know if ‘they’ *will go* to the concert, if ‘they’ will take actions to get closer to the concert hall, then the perfective aspect is needed:

> *Они пойдут на концерт?* — Will they **start** moving from their place to the place where the concert will be? (will the action start?)

If you use the imperfective aspect, *будут идти*, the meaning will be more about the present:

> *Они будут идти на концерт?* — Do you/they **now** think they will go to the concert? (is the situation **now** such that in the future they will go to the concert?)

If your intention is to find out whether ‘they’ will *be at* the concert, then the perfective verb *прийти* is the best choice:

> *Они придут на концерт?* — Will they come to and stay at the concert?

However, note the *go* vs. *come* difference in the pair *пойти — прийти.*

**UPD.** In fact, using the present tense verb is also OK (only imperfective aspect verbs can have present tense). *Они **идут** на концерт?* means “Are they going to the concert?” both in the meaning of ‘on their way right now’ and also ‘planning to go’.

Comment: Also could mention "Они сходят на концерт"

Comment: Нет, "сходят" это совсем не "пойдут".